# split the video in few parts, encode each part in base64 in android

Tags: android, video, base64

In my app I'm upload big size of video as base64 string form and it causes outofmemory error. There is one solution to prevent that is split the video in few parts, encode each part in base64 but I don't know how to do it as I'm not much experienced in android application development?

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
        // Converting the video in to the bytes
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(selectedMediaUri)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len = 0;
        try {
            assert inputStream != null;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String videoData = Base64.encodeToString(byteBuffer.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Base64` use `multipart` for uploading a file, this will solve your problem.

Comment: web service accept base64 as a input thats why I have to convert it in base64.

Comment: ok. In which type of variable you are storing this base64 data.

Comment: I'm storing base64 data in string variable. and thank for reply.

Comment: instead of storing in string use StringBuilder

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append(data); do this and try

Comment: Still face same issue.